# Как вывести на экран имя переменной?

Tags: java, переменные, типы, имена

Допустим есть Класс с десятками/сотнями полей. Есть геттеры и сеттеры. Нужно вывести на экран имена всех полей. Пусть:

```
int var = 666;
String field = "El Diablo";
```

В консоли нужно получить: **var field** и всё!
Ну на худой конец сойдут и имена геттеров **getVar getField**, например.

Вообще, в идеале мне б ещё и типы переменных вывести на экран по-простому, а то мне пришлось писать отдельный Класс типа **TypeOfVar**.

Comment: Где-то тут: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/

Comment: За Парсинг спасибо, если б знал что это существует, не задал бы вопрос.

Comment: @JürgenvonMarkoff не забудьте чуть больше почитать про рефлексию (reflection)

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский прочитал! Спасибо ещё раз!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примерно так

```
//Получаем список полей класса А
Field[] declaredFields = A.class.getDeclaredFields();
//перебираем
for (Field field : declaredFields) {
    //Выводим имя поля
    System.out.println(field.getName());
    //Выводим тип поля
    System.out.println(field.getType());
}
```